# Fetching client id and client secret of a Salesforce connected app from backend

Tags: automation, salesforce

Is there a way to fetch the client id and client secret of a Salesforce connected app from backend (through any apex code or anything) without using the UI? I am actually working on Salesforce API automation so need to fetch these in runtime and store in string variables to use them in the API request headers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Metadata API to retrieve details of connected app(s). Sample XML you'd get is at the bottom of https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_connectedapp.htm

I don't think there's a pure Apex solution, you might have some luck with this Apex wrapper for the callouts: https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi

If you're after automation you might want to look into creating connected apps on the fly? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oidc_dynamic_client_reg_flow.htm&type=5